# How to perform a symbolic minimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Can *Mathematica* determine the symbolic expression in terms of `τ` that minimizes `f[τ]` ?

```
u[τ_] := n*E^(-λ*τ)  
f1[τ_] := k*τ
f2[τ_] := a*u[τ]
f3[τ_] := m*τ^2
f[τ_] := f1[τ] + f2[τ] + f3[τ]

f[τ]
```

> ```
> a E^(-λ τ) n + k τ + m τ^2
> ```

So far so good. But when I use `Minimize`, it just gives back my input.

```
Minimize[f[τ], τ, Reals]
```

> ```
> Minimize[a E^(-λ τ) n + k τ + m τ^2, τ, Reals]
> ```

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about lambda, a, m, n and k? For example, n > 0 etc.

Comment: All of the constants must be real and greater than zero.

Comment: For good formatting practice see [editing-help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). [This](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor/1044#1044) browser extension is also useful.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it using Minimize, but the answer can be obtained from `Solve[D[f[t], t] == 0, t]`. f[t] has only one extremum and it is minimum.

Comment: Bingo Kamov ! I verified your solution numerically and it is spot on. Once again Mathematica did not let me down. But it is interesting that Minimize didn't "know" to call Solve for help. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Note that we wouldn't "know" how to solve the problem as stated -- crucial information is found only in a comment.  Without these conditions, the function sometimes does not have a minimum.  Also note that `Solve` warns that it doesn't know that there is only one solution to `f'[t] == 0`. (You might consider revising your question to include the conditions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calculating a derivative it is easy to see that you get an equation

```
    D[f[\[Tau]], \[Tau]] == 0

(* k - a E^(-\[Lambda] \[Tau]) n \[Lambda] + 2 m \[Tau] == 0  *)
```

It is non-polynomial and non-linear. Equations of that sort Mathematica cannot solve analytically. For this reason Minimize does not work. You could try it numerically.